# C++ enum in a constructor?

Tags: c++, enums

Im trying to pass an enum to a constructor. Below is my class declaration in my h file

```
class Events
{

private:
    enum events
    {
        hundredMetre,
        DiscusThrow,
        highJump,
        fivehundredMetre,
        hurdle,
        shotput,
        relay,
        longJump
    };
    
    std::string eventName;
    bool eventType; //standard or field
    std::string unitofTime;

public:
    Events();
    Events(std::string, bool, std::string, enum);
};
```

As shown in my public declarations i have a default constructor and then a constructor that takes parametres. The last type Im passing is an enum. This enum is the first variable declared under private. However this line of code `Events(std::string, bool, std::string, enum);` causes an error to occur where `enum` is used. The error is question is `expected either a definition or a tag name`

How can I use my enum in my contructor declaration?

Comment: The type name is `events` not `enum`. Also since your enum definition is `private`, no one would be able to call your constructor from outside of that class.

Comment: Besides what was already said, you most of the time want to use scoped enums (`enum class events { … }`).